# zsh function: maximum nested function level reached

Tags: bash, fedora, zsh, function

Consider this simple function I am trying to add in my `.aliases` (`dnf` is Fedoras newest replacement of Yum):

```
function abc() {
    dnf search something
}
```

It works well on Bash but I get the following problem on `zsh`:

```
dnf:1: maximum nested function level reached
```

What can be the cause of this problem?

---

```
$ type -a dnf
dnf is /usr/bin/dnf
dnf is /bin/dnf
```

Comment: I've evited my question.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `type -a dnf`

Comment: Try and run it after having issued `set -x`.

Comment: dnf is /usr/bin/dnf
dnf is /bin/dnf
dnf is /bin/dnf

Comment: Use `/usr/bin/dnf` inside the function. I have similar problem with `/usr/bin/ln` when creating a soft link.